# Problems with keyboard and mouse: shortcuts work 20% of the time, mouse no longer drags correctly

Tags: keyboard, mouse, windows-11, wireless-mouse

**Hardware Issues**

I am running Windows 11. I have a Logitech wireless mouse (with USB dongle) and a Klim wireless mechanical keyboard (also with USB dongle).

**What is happening?**

About two weeks ago, both the mouse and the keyboard started to become less responsive.
Both work very well for single button clicks, but I have trouble with any action that requires a combination of buttons or long actions.

**Example**

For example, if I try to use "CTRL+A" to select some text, the keyboard outputs an "a" about 80% of the time. For the mouse, if I drag a window around or select text, about 80% of the time the mouse is released before the action is complete (meaning only part of the text is selected or the window stays where it is). Overall, the problem is not very consistent and the percentages vary.

**Assumption**

What seems to be happening is a micro-cutoff of the signal.

**What I have tried**

I have tried the following:

1. Switching the USB port used for both keyboard and mouse
2. Checking the sticky keys and filter keys in Windows
3. Run the keyboard troubleshooter
4. Checked drivers (seem to be up to date)
5. Created a new user session (same issue)
6. Switched keyboard to Bluetooth connection instead of USB dongle, even used full wired connection

I am running out of ideas and this issue is really impacting my productivity. Any help or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Since you've tried the existing keyboard wired, you might 1. Temporarily substitute a different wired keyboard. If that works, you know the keyboard was bad.  If there are still issues, 2. Try booting from USB, e.g.,  Win PE/RE or Linux, and type in Notepad or gedit. If that works, the issue is in Win11, not the keyboard; reinstall from ISO.

Comment: You don't mention what is running in startup.  That would be my first guess.  Also, the display driver can indeed play a role here but you say you checked drivers.  Did this include display?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The cleanup image didn't help here. I redid my cable management yesterday and tried the mouse and keyboard on my Mac. This morning everything seems to be working normally... after 2 weeks. I have no idea why. I haven't changed anything on the software side.

If I find the cause, I will definitely answer the question myself.